# python dataframe to csv fixed char length for all cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to figure out a way to print dataframe to csv file (with tab as sep, and I won't be interested in reading it back as csv in the future) that looks nice. See these pix for example. [undesired format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtedf.png) [desired format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6MbG.png)

Now I have figured out a way to do this by:

1. converting existing headers to a list.
2. iterate thru all the items in the aforementioned list, cast them as string, use ljust to a fixed length (by adding trailing spaces) to the highest char count and assign them back to same list
3. re-assign the header list back to the df
4. iterate thru all the rest of the df cells, cast them as string, use ljust to a fixed length that's the highest char count for all cells and re-assign them back to their previous position.
5. use to_csv with sep = "\t"

and the output csv looks like what I want but I wonder if there is an existing method associated with pandas that can do this in an automated fashion? ie, figure out the highest char count, add trailing spaces accordingly and the print to csv that looks like nice table without having to copying and pasting them into a spread sheet.

Answer (score 0):

There is a contradiction in what you are asking:

- If you want the output to be valid CSV (i.e. could be read back via `pd.read_csv()`), then you may use `sep='\t'`, but your columns will be jagged (there will be only 1 `'\t'` separating each column.
- if, on the other hand, you'd like to make the file such that columns are aligned, then you should use `df.to_string(index=False)`. But then that is not a CSV file.
- finally, you could *modify* the data by padding with spaces, and even make it so it's still valid CSV (still with `sep='\t'`), but then you'll have a different data when you read it back.

#### Examples:

In all the examples below, we don't specify a file to write to, so the output is a string and we print that. Pass a filename as first argument to `.to_csv()` or `.to_string()` to write to a file.

##### Setup

with an extra column for a bit more generality:

```py
# setup
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Saul Goodman', 'JMM'],
    'foo': ['hello', 'wonderful world'],
    'age': [49, 50],
})
```

##### Valid tab-separated CSV

```py
# tab-separated CSV
>>> print(df.to_csv(sep='\t', index=False))
name    foo age
Saul Goodman    hello   49
JMM wonderful world 50
```

##### not a CSV, all columns visually aligned

```py
# to string (all columns are aligned)
>>> print(df.to_string(index=False))
        name             foo  age
Saul Goodman           hello   49
         JMM wonderful world   50
```

##### Padded string columns and tab-separated

Still valid CSV (tab-separated), but the data is *modified* (padded):

```py
strcols = df.dtypes == 'O'
strcols = strcols[strcols].index.tolist()
lens = df[strcols].applymap(len).max()

rename = {k: f'{k:<{v}s}' for k, v in lens.items()}
>>> print(df.assign(**{
...     k: df[k].str.pad(v, 'right')
...     for k, v in lens.items()
... }).rename(rename, axis=1).to_csv(index=False, sep='\t'))
name            foo             age
Saul Goodman    hello           49
JMM             wonderful world 50
```